# Checking if a button was clicked and what was clicked

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and HTML, I was creating my first website and I found that I would have to repeat a header over and over so I put it in a 'Header.php' file and included it now I have the problem of checking what page they goto. I need to know what page they goto so I can place a 'class="active"' on the page they goto. I may need the code written for me if it isn't too long. Even an example of how you  do it showing all the elements will help. Anyhow heres my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Metamorphosis Design Free Css Templates</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="link_is_clicked" name="link_is_clicked" value="0"/> 
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bg_top">
            <div id="wrap_bg">
                <div id="wrap">
                    <div id="header">
                        <div id="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="but1_menu"><a href="index.php"class="active">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="but2_menu"><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
                                <li class="but3_menu"><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                                <li class="but4_menu"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                                <li class="but5_menu"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="logo">
                            <h1><a href="#">metamorph_strongrey</a></h1>
                            <a href="#"><small>Small Company Slogan Goes Here</small></a>
                        </div>
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: If I understand the question, you want the "active" class to be added to the appropriate list-item in the menu?

Comment: @Leon provide a link otherwise that comment doesn't help anyone.

Comment: [Here's documentation on the `$_SERVER` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Lots of info can be obtained by testing the values of its indexes.

Comment: @user1591117 http://tut.php-quake.net/en/ is a decent php tutorial in my opinion. A bit outdated though.
HTML I recommend to learn here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/default.asp

Comment: Plau well I dont need tutorials. The only thing I'm stick with is this. Once I can get this out of my way the rest will be easy as PHP is a C++ based language and i know C++. I have dobne work on this if you dont relise this came all HTML and I had to place headers and footers to save my self time during editing. I know how

Comment: to make click to edit things on the site. I can code PHP and HTML the only problem is this. I dont need to be told go read a tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

When it's a small list like you have, I normally would go with a simple `if` statement:

```
<li class="but1_menu"><a href="index.php"<?=(($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=='index.php')?' class="active"':'');?>>Home</a></li>
<li class="but2_menu"><a href="blog.php"<?=(($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=='blog.php')?' class="active"':'');?>>Blog</a></li>
<li class="but3_menu"><a href="gallery.php"<?=(($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=='gallery.php')?' class="active"':'');?>>Gallery</a></li>
<li class="but4_menu"><a href="about.php"<?=(($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=='about.php')?' class="active"':'');?>>About Us</a></li>
<li class="but5_menu"><a href="contact.php"<?=(($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=='contact.php')?' class="active"':'');?>>Contact Us</a></li>
```

This will check the current script's name via [`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and if it matches, it will echo `class="active"`.

Comment: @user1591117 Did you copy+paste, or try to rewrite it yourself? Ignoring the fact that if you copy+paste it would be impossible for all of them to have `class="active"`, I just tested it and it works as you want it to.

Comment: http://i49.tinypic.com/elb9m9.png

I copyed and pasted it and thats exactly how I see your code after its implemented.

http://i46.tinypic.com/1zvrcko.png

Heres the code in a text editor:

Answer (score 2):

First step: Get the current page the user is visiting

```
$current_url = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
```

Second step: Create an array containing all menu link pages

```
$all_urls = array('index.php', 'blog.php', 'gallery.php', 'about.php', 'contact.php');
```

Third step: Check if the current url is inside the array. If yes, apply the class

```
<ul>        
    <li class="but1_menu"><a href="index.php" <?php if(in_array($current_url, $all_urls)){echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>Home</a></li>
    <li class="but2_menu"><a href="blog.php" <?php if(in_array($current_url, $all_urls)){echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>Blog</a></li>
    <li class="but3_menu"><a href="gallery.php" <?php if(in_array($current_url, $all_urls)){echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="but4_menu"><a href="about.php" <?php if(in_array($current_url, $all_urls)){echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>About Us</a></li>
    <li class="but5_menu"><a href="contact.php" <?php if(in_array($current_url, $all_urls)){echo 'class="active"'; } ?>>Contact Us</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is place in the `href` parameter of your anchor tags `<a>`, a query string indicating what link was pressed.

```
<a href="about.php?action=about">About Us</a>
```

Now in your PHP code, you'll want to take a look at the [`$_GET` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).  It is an associative array of all the parameters passed in the URL.  So `$_GET['action']` will be equal to `about`.

When you come to write your header once again and want to indicate a "active" link by adding a class, you can just test the `action` element of the `$_GET` variable.

Lets assume that in your header file you have an array of links like this -

```
$headerLinks = array(
  'about' => array(
     'href'=>'about.php?action=about',
     'title'=>'About Us' 
  ),
  'home' => array(
     'href'=>'home.php?action=home',
     'title'=>'Home' 
  ),
  'blag' => array(
     'href'=>'blag.php?action=blag',
     'title'=>'Our Blag' 
  ),
  ...
);
```

You would loop over the contents of that array to create your links with the appropriate on having the `active` class.

```
foreach($headerLinks AS $key => $link){
  $isActive = $_GET['action'] == $key? 'active' : '';
  echo '<a href="'.$link['href'].'" class="'.$isActive.'">'.$link['title'].'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However I tryed this and I happen to recive loads of writing over my buttons instead of the buttons which are highlighted..

Comment: That sounds to me like a problem with invalid HTML... You should check and double check your code for HTML tags that are not being terminated properly... This can cause some unpredictable results...

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Specifically the part about REQUEST_URI and that will be what you need. Simply check for this in an if or case statement and apply your class as needed.

You'll only need a few lines of code to check for the uris in your nav bar.

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` also contains the query-string; `SCRIPT_NAME` is the specific PHP file.

Comment: Not sure why, works for me. Just try googling "php server variables" it should be the first result.

Comment: I will google it in a second :). I'm just fidnlign with the code another guy gave me as he says it should work but it doesnt :(. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

One more method.

Your page will look like

```
<?php 
   $curr = "gallery";
   include('header.php');
?>
```

where the $curr variable has a value which could be found in the menu below

and now the menu

```
                        <li class="but1_menu"><a <?php echo ($curr == "index" ? "class='active'" : "" ); ?> href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="but2_menu"><a <?php echo ($curr == "blog" ? "class='active'" : "" ); ?> href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="but3_menu"><a <?php echo ($curr == "gallery" ? "class='active'" : "" ); ?> href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li class="but4_menu"><a <?php echo ($curr == "about_us" ? "class='active'" : "" ); ?> href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="but5_menu"><a <?php echo ($curr == "contact_us" ? "class='active'" : "" ); ?> href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
```

To keep code clean is better to use short if/else statement because there is no complex stuff.

Also i recommend to you to put "active" class on `<li>` but this depends by the style of each developer. In some complex menus it will help you very much.